# Is it possible to obtain noise level in electrons using only one camera?

Tags: noise, camera, sensor

In the link, https://www.photonstophotos.net/GeneralTopics/Sensors_&_Raw/Sensor_Analysis_Primer/Photon_Transfer_Curve.htm

there is one figured called Standard Photon Transfer Curve – Multiple ISOs in electrons. The noise level is given in units per electrons. Without detained information about the sensor such full-well capacity, is it possible to measure noise level in electrons using only one camera? For example, I buy one camera and have a light box, how can I get the noise level in electrons if possible?

Comment: Multiply the noise in adu's by the gain? It is hard to know what to make of your question without more context and details of the camera and what you are using it for.

Comment: @ProfRob I am surprised to find the link includes noise level in units of electrons for a DSLR cameras and mobile phones. How can the measurements be obtained? Usually the detailed information of the sensors used is not available.

Comment: @ProfRob As you said, how is the system gain measured if the gain is used? Is there any requirement to measure system gain?